# Can we extract an injective envelope from a monomorphism?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, injective-modules

Let $A$ be an artinian ring and $f : X \rightarrow \bigoplus_{j=1}^{n}I_{j}$ be a morphism of $A$-modules, where each $I_{j}$ is injective and indecomposable. If $f$ is a monomorphism, then can we conclude that there is an injective envelope $g : X \rightarrow \bigoplus_{t=1}^{m}I_{j_{t}}$? (Here $\{ j_1, \ldots, j_m \} \subset \{1, \ldots, n \}$)

Comment: For $n=1$, this would mean that any monomorphism into an injective module is an injective envelope...

Comment: @abx you are right... I changed the question now in a clever way. Thank you.

Comment: @abx it is not true that the injective envelope is indecomposable

Comment: You are right, sorry. I delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: given a monomorphism $f\colon X\to I$ with $I$ injective, as in the question, you can find a decomposition $I=I_0\oplus I_1$ such that $f=\begin{pmatrix}f_0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $f_0\colon X\to I_0$ is left minimal, so it is an injective envelope.

Getting this decomposition does not require any assumption on the ring $R$, and only much weaker assumptions on $I$, for example that it is pure injective. A good reference is [*On minimal approximations of modules*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.554.9503&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Krause and Saorín.